# manually input in textbox and connected to the server

Tags: c#, sockets

Right now, when i press the connect button i will be connected to the server by the default ip address and port number.   clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);

I would like to create 2 textbox in the GUI , 1 for the IP address and 1 for port.
So that user can manually key in the IP add and port.
May i know how to do this. thanks.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace SocketClient
{

```
public partial class SocketClient : Form
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
    string readData = null;


    public SocketClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + returndata;
            msg();
        }
    }


    private void msg()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(msg));
        else
            textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
    }


    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        readData = "Conected to NYP Chat Server ...";
        msg();
        //
        clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textName.Text + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
        ctThread.Start();
    }


    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textDisplay_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the designer view, add two TextBoxes in the desired positions and name the texbboxes as tbIp and tbPort.

update the line following line
clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);
to
clientSocket.Connect(tbIp.Text, Convert.Int32(tbPort.Text));

Regards
ArunDhaJ

Comment: i have an error saying 'system.convert' does not contain a destination for 'int32'

Comment: i know the error already. Convert.ToInt32(tbPort.Text));
u left out the To